# how to get parent object property in foreach function

Tags: javascript, object, this

for example
I can't reach 'this.ret' so use 'obj.ret' in loop.

is this right way?

```
const obj = {
  ret : 0,
  sum : function(arr){
     $.each(arr, function(i, v){
         obj.ret += v //Can't reach this.ret
     })
     this.print();
  },
  print : function(){
    alert('sum is ' + this.ret)
  }
}

    
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
obj.sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
const obj = {
  ret : 0,
  sum : function(arr){
     $.each(arr, (i, v) => {
         this.ret += v
     })
     this.print();
  },
  print : function(){
    console.log('sum is ' + this.ret)
  }
}

    
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
obj.sum(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  ret : 0,
  sum : function(arr){
     $.each(arr, function(i, v){
         obj.ret += v //Can't reach this.ret
     })
     this.print();
  },
  print : function(){
    console.log('sum is ' + this.ret)
  }
}

    
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
obj.sum(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

change `obj.sum()` to `obj.sum(arr)`